# CSS display inputs in-line (last input width:100%)

Tags: html, css

I need to create a line with a few inputs  and to be sure they always fill the div, I've added `width:100%` to the last input

```
<div style="width:300px;background:#eee;height:30px">
    <input value="first" style="width:80px" type="button"/>
    <input value="second" style="width:80px" type="button"/>
    <input value="last" style="width:100%" type="button"/>
</div>
```

This sample is not working fine because the last input width is same as div's and it appears in the second line.

How can I make them all appear in the same line?

**[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k2Nqp/)**

Comment: If you know beforehand the container `width`, why try to guess the last `div width`?

Comment: why don't you divide 100% among controls?

Comment: `width: 100%` is going to give the last input 100% width of the container. Can you use a fixed width for all inputs?

Comment: Yes, but the original document contains 6 to 11 inputs all at different size. Plus they dynamically change?

Comment: So you want the last button to fill the remaining space? It doesn't make sense as the container has a fixed width??

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With a little CSS you can do this. Wrap the last input in a span and add this CSS:

```
<div style="width:300px;background:#eee;height:30px;">
    <input value="first" style="width:80px" type="button"/>
    <input value="second" style="width:80px" type="button"/>
    <span id="last"><input value="last" style="width:100%" type="button" /></span>
</div>
#last {
    overflow:auto;
    display:block;
}
input {
    float:left;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/k2Nqp/4/)**

Comment: this is perfect.  I've looked at a dozen similar questions and answers and everything either: 1) ignored the question and answered with fixed widths, or 2) was about a page worth of questionable css.  This was succinct and did exactly what was needed, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you use width: 100%, this fills the div containing the input.  The best way to have them all fit inside is the distribute the div width evenly between the inputs, and float them so they all sit next to each other.

```
<div style="width:300px;background:#eee;height:30px">
<input value="first" style="width:100px, float: left;" type="button"/>
<input value="second" style="width:100px" type="button"/>
<input value="last" style="width:100px, float: right;" type="button"/>
</div>
```

The syntax might not be exactly right, I rarely use in-line CSS, much better off just giving the inputs and class and then assigning the class with attributes in your .css file.

Comment: Another viable option is to find a percentage width that is approximate to his 80px value given the container size, then do the math and give the last div the remaining space.

Comment: Exactly ^
Can you use em too, but I was just demonstrating a method.

Answer (score 0):

You can Try for fill your div from button

```
<div style="width:300px;background:#eee;height:30px">
    <input value="first" style="width:80px" type="button"/>
    <input value="second" style="width:80px" type="button"/>
    <input value="last" style="width:132px" type="button"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `N` children that you want to render to fit some width, then you need to set their respective widths to `100% / N`, which for your example would be `100% / 3` ~33.33333% However, (unless you have `box-sizing: border-box/padding-box` set) you also need to account for margins, borders and padding. Furthermore, if your elements are `display: inline` or `display: inline-block` the whitespace between them in the source will also take up space. You need to counter this whitespace by

- Removing it
- Undoing it with `margin-right: -0.4em` or some value that works
- `float` your elements (which actually sets `display: block`)

I've [updated your demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k2Nqp/5/) with the quickest solution that gives you your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

```
<b
   style={{
          fontFamily: "arch",
          fontSize: 50
              }}>
</b>


<div style={{
                marginTop: 20,
                marginLeft:"280px",
                marginRight:"80px",
                fontSize: 40}}>
</div>
```

LIke this you can do in **JSX**